How to create simple linear chart?
I try to create a simple chart with several lines and common axis. Lines are given by sets of points, points with x and y - integers. Fg Line 1 is [{x: 10, y: 10},{x: 20, y: 15},{x: 30, y: 10},{x: 40, y: 12},{x: 50, y: 10}] and Line 2 is [{x: 10, y: 10},{x: 17, y: 11},{x: 22, y: 28},{x: 35, y: 44},{x: 53, y: 16}]. Values of x are diffrent. I'd like to have one chart with 2 lines. Each line should have Bezier approximation. The range of x axis should be defined, fg from 10 to 53 in the example above.
How to create such a chart in chart.js?

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html

How to use chart.js drawing multiple lines from line sets with (X, Y) values?

You'll need a scatter plot for non-uniform X coordinates:


const d1 = [{x: 10, y: 10},{x: 20, y: 15},{x: 30, y: 10},{x: 40, y: 12},{x: 50, y: 10}];
const d2 = [{x: 10, y: 10},{x: 17, y: 11},{x: 22, y: 28},{x: 35, y: 44},{x: 53, y: 16}];
const config = {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: {
    datasets: [{data: d1, showLine: true}, {data: d2, showLine: true}],
  },
};

new Chart(document.getElementById('c'), config);
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.4.7/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>



